# Squid HTTPS intercept generates certifcate for IP instead of hostname

Tags: ssl, squid

I'm new to Squid, and having trouble getting SSL filtering work.

I have a blanket block setup with Squid as Transparent proxy where access it allowed only to github.com. But, squid generates certificates for IP address instead of domain name and SSL validation fails.

Squid version: `3.5.25-20170408-r14154`

When I use curl (I have imported my self signed SSL to the certificate store)

`curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (192.30.255.112) does not match target host name 'github.com'`

How to configure properly to splice a whitelist and block all other domains. Below is my current configuration

```
http_port 3128
http_port 3129 intercept
https_port 3130intercept ssl-bump enerate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB 
cert=/etc/squid/ssl_certs/myca.pem key=/etc/squid/ssl_certs/myca.pem

acl whitelist ssl::server_name .github.com
acl step1 at_step SslBump1

ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump splice whitelist
ssl_bump bump all
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Squid 4.

I had the same issue, and I switched to [Squid 4](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v4/) (Which is still in  development).With the same configurations in the question squid 4 will generate certificates with proper hostname.